# MaterialUI Align drawer items to the bottom

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have the following drawer component for which I want the items to be alignt at the bottom but the header should stay on top.:

```
              <Drawer
                open={this.state.drawerOpen}
                onClose={this.toggleDrawer(false)}
                sx={{ alignItems: "flex-end" }}
              >
                <DrawerHeader>
                  <IconButton onClick={this.toggleDrawer(false)}>
                    <ChevronLeftIcon />
                  </IconButton>
                </DrawerHeader>

                <Divider />
                {this.drawerMenuList()}
                <Divider />
                <List>
                  <ListItemButton
                    onClick={(event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
                      this.handleOpenNavMenuItem(`/login`, event);
                    }}
                  >
                    <ListItemIcon>
                      <LogoutIcon />
                    </ListItemIcon>
                    <ListItemText primary="Logout" />
                  </ListItemButton>
                </List>
              </Drawer>
```

The problem is nothing worked so far I tried with a Box (<Box sx={{ alignContent: 'flex-end' }}) around the list also with a grid with direction="column" and justifyContent="flex-end" and also a flex box which strech between header and list but nothing seems to work.

What am I missing here?